# Populate new rows while iterating some elements in the dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, rows

I trying to read a csv file containing a cell (which comes after skipping 28 rows). Using the following code,

```
import os, csv
import pandas as pd

file="testfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=28, delimiter=";")
df.iloc[0:0]
```

cell A29 is read - which outputs a list

```
[SS_1; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; N; -0.6; testfile]
```

I want to have the following output from cells A30 to A61

```
[SS_2; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; FILE_Year00_-0.6%modrate.csv; -0.6;]
[SS_3; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; FILE_Year01_-0.3%modrate.csv; -0.3;]
[SS_4; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; FILE_Year02_0%modrate.csv; 0;]
[SS_5; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; FILE_Year03_0.3%modrate.csv; 0.3;]
[SS_6; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; FILE_Year04_0.6%modrate.csv; 0.6;]

                              .
                              .
                              .

[SS_32; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; N; FILE_Year30_8.4%modrate.csv; 8.4;]
```

As you can see there is iteration invloved with elements **SS_, FILE_Yearxx_xx%modrate.csv, -0.6.** 
Can anyone suggest easiest way to operate with existing dataframe or should I make a new df with for loop?

Comment: What is `df.shape` ? Is it a 1 column dataframe that you want to split into 4 columns?

Comment: It is 1 x7. All the operation is in single column. I want to read a single cell A 29 which reads `SS_1; FC2; Computer_1995.SFX; N; -0.6; testfile;`  I want to fill cells A30 to A61 of the same column A while iterating some of the elements as shown above

Comment: Sorry shape is 2 x 7. There is also a ";" in one of the cells A33. In the output file I want to keep the ";" and move it down to A64 while inserting the desired output in the cells of first column. Thanks